# In Azure Data Factory how to read XML response

Tags: api, odata, azure-data-factory

As I am new to ADF, looking for the right way to read/accept XML response from an API.

Tried the following activities using copy activity,

- Rest, linked service. Linked service connection is successful but while previewing the error,
  [image]
- HTTP, linked service. Linked service connection is successful but while previewing the error,
  [image]
- OData, linked service. failed to connect to the linked service Error: Failed to create odata connection to RequestUrl.
  [image]

It would be helpful if someone could share a doc or reference on how XML API response can be consumed in the ADF.

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#rest-as-source),  REST connector only support response in JSON.

[image]

---

**EDIT -**

Unfortunately XML response is not supported. You can use an ADF Custom activity to transform the XML programmatically.

Refer - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/68c41a5d-4cd3-4f61-8cbf-c9d86909ce80/adf-v2-pull-from-rest-api-that-returns-xml?forum=AzureDataFactory

Comment: Yeah, so how to read XML data?